# typos in the FAQ list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

1. [The FAQ list](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#askpatents) has:

> On September 16th, 2012, the America Invents Act (AIA) became law.

And then:

> The USPTO Prior Art Submission Site, scheduled for launch on September 16, 2012, will deliver prior art directly to examiners at the USPTO.

Either the FAQ list is assuming September 16th's come and gone, in which case the information about the submission site should be in past tense, or not, in which case the information about the statute should be in future tense.

2. [The FAQ list](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art) has "1800." instead of "1800s".

Answer (score 3):

The "future tense" references were made in preparation of the *public* release of this site *after* that date. Remember that this site is still in *private* beta, and our primary task now is to prepare this site for opening day when it is announced to the general public.

But I did fix that '1800s' reference. Thanks.

Comment: Re "The 'future tense' references were made in preparation of the public release of this site after that date.": That's what I'd thought, actually — but then the "scheduled for launch" reference needs editing.